# Hyper V and NAT Redirect IP on different VM

Tags: ip, hyper-v, nat

I have 2 IPs public (but one physical network port) and i want redirect IP public 1 on my VM 1 and, IP public 2 on my VM 2

But when i check my NAT configuration i can just redirect port on my interne network, but i have not choice of my second IP

How can i choice : IP public 1 port xx ==> redirection Ip intern (192.168.1.10) port xx and
IP public 2 port xx ==> redirection Ip intern (192.168.1.11) port xx

My host is Windows Server 2012 r2 , Hyper-V

If you have anothers questions on my configuration leave me a comment

Many Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing this configuration from within RRAS?  I would like to duplicate the steps you are trying and go from there.